# How to add json array at the end of url in Android using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, httpurlconnection

Recently In a project, I had to face an API from my colleague which accepts JSON arrays of an object in the URL with GET method.

For example, the call to API is

```
api.site.com/object/create/[{"id":1,"name":"Hello!"},{"id":2,"name":"World!"}]
```

This URL perfectly works with Chrome and the API returns the expected value which is for example: `[{"id":12501}]`

But in Android, the functions that handled throws a
 **java.net.SocketTimeoutException**

The code is as below:

```
public String makeMVCServiceCall(String url,Method method,String additionalInformation)

{
    url=url+"/"+additionalInformation;
    return makeServiceCall(url,method);
}
public String makeServiceCall(String url,Method method)
{
    HttpURLConnection connection=null;
    try
    {
        URL u=new URL(url);
        connection=(HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
        String m=method== Method.GET?"GET":method== Method.POST?"POST":null;
        connection.setRequestMethod(m);        

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);            
        connection.connect();
        int status=0;
        String response=connection.getResponseMessage();            
        status=connection.getResponseCode();


        switch (status)
        {
            case 200:
            case 201:

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();

                return sb.toString();
            default:                    
                return null;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally {
        if(connection!=null)
            try
            {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Timeouts are 5 seconds, changing them to 15  seconds didn't make any difference. I think it is a bad practice to attach a JSON object at the end of the URL, but I have to use that API.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Never catch an exception without logging it. You do that in two places in your code. In fact, it is unclear how you are determining that this is a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete them when pasting the code. I caught them with e.getClass()

Comment: Are you making any other calls to this server that are working? IOW, is this issue limited to just this one request, or is it possible that you are facing bigger issues, being unable to communicate with the server at all?

Comment: Write the code for the method which calls the function `makeMVCServiceCall(...)` as the code you have pasted is just fine. It must be a problem with the url. Also paste the entire stack trace

Comment: Yes I do, there is four other requests using this function and they are working perfectly. But this one does not work, I tried to use URLEncoder but nothing change and one time I got 400 Bad Request Error.

Comment: @Sepinood:Instead of passing json through url, You can try this :
OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write(new Gson().toJson(your object));

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the additional parameters:

`URLEncoder.encode(additionalInformation)`

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? if yes then you need to set jvm proxy:   
http.proxyHost=[domain or IP]  
http.proxyPort=[port number]

Comment: No, my device directly connected to Internet.